# Buttons in HTML not executing onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, web

After creating buttons they don't react while clicking on them like if the function specified in `onclick` attribute weren't defined or attribute didn't exist at all

I've tried:

1. Manually testing functions in console
2. Using different browsers (I've tested: Edge, Chrome, Brave, Firefox, Opera, Tor)
3. Defining the function in other way
4. Using `<button>` instead of `<input type="button>"`

I expect the function to properly execute after each button press and therefore a change in `button.value`

What I got:

1. Function works, so its the button that doesn't execute it
2. It isn't problem with compatibility/browser
3. Function is defined correctly, no matter how it is defined it works fine in console
4. Button for some reason refreshed all page instead of executing function

```html
<form id="game" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but0" onclick="click(0)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but1" onclick="click(1)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but2" onclick="click(2)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but3" onclick="click(3)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but4" onclick="click(4)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but5" onclick="click(5)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but6" onclick="click(6)">     
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but7" onclick="click(7)">
    <input type="button" class="but" id="but8" onclick="click(8)">
</form>
```

```js
function click(but) {
    switch (but) {
        case 0:
            if (v0 != undefined) { return v0 }
            v0 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but0`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 1:
            if (v1 != undefined) { return v1 }
            v1 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but1`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (v2 != undefined) { return v2 }
            v2 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but2`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (v3 != undefined) { return v3 }
            v3 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but3`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (v4 != undefined) { return v4 }
            v4 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but4`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 5:
            if (v5 != undefined) { return v5 }
            v5 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but5`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 6:
            if (v6 != undefined) { return v6 }
            v6 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but6`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 7:
            if (v7 != undefined) { return v7 }
            v7 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but7`).value = rnd;
            break;
        case 8:
            if (v8 != undefined) { return v8 }
            v8 = rnd;
            document.getElementById(`but8`).value = rnd;
            break;
    }
    update()
    if (rnd == '❌') {
        rnd = '⭕'
        return '❌'
    }
    else {
        rnd = '❌'
        return '⭕'
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to your code as links can die over time, making your question here useless. Please edit your question to include the RELEVANT code right here.

Comment: *Button for some reason refreshed all page instead of executing function* <-- Probably because you didn't specify a `type="button"` for the `<button>` element. If you don't do that, the button will act as a `submit` button.

Comment: I feel like 95% of the time, questions of this ilk arise because users either don't know or don't care how to open the JavaScript debugger

Comment: FYI - the function works, you can tell by changing to logic to do a console.log on click. The issue exists with how you are trying to set the value of the input boxes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for a tip about `<button>`, but it doesn't matter

Comment: i think onClick should be capital C...and maybe need to pass the function instead of the string

Comment: @1ak31sha it doesn't work either

Comment: @Kjur0 what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: *thanks for a tip about <button>, but it doesn't matter* <-- Yeah, it absolutely does. If that one change doesn't solve your problem, then you've got another problem as well.  if you want a button that can respond to a `click` event and NOT submit your form (which it what causes the page to refresh), then you need `type="button"` on your `button` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a bit silly, but the reason why your buttons do nothing is because `click` is reserved in the context of the element. Try it, set `onclick="console.log(click)"`, and you'll see that it shows a function with native code. To fix your problem, rename your function `click` to something else, like `myClick` and the collision disappears.

**edit:**

to see what function 'click' is really calling, [it's this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you. After so much time the answer was so easy

Comment: @DCR im sorry, i dont understand. im just explaining why the buttons do nothing. `click` is different in the context of an html element and would override any outside definitions

Comment: Of course the best way is to [not use inline HTML event attributes in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) as they are outdated relics of the days before we had standards.

Answer (score -2):

Try using onClick with capital 'C'.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: It won't work, cause it it `onclick`. I double checked that in documentation

Comment: @Kjur0 HTML is not case-sensitive. You can capitalize `onclick` any way you want. Whatever "documentation" you looked at is inaccurate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).